# Whats the proper way to allow(optional) spaces for groups?

Tags: regex

```
/(\w+)\s+?([a-z][A-Z])\s+?(\w+)/
```

Right now I'm using `\s+?` to allow(optional) spaces, is this the proper way of doing it?

Comment: \s+ is one or more space, if you want optional you should probably use \s*

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I was wondering if this is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Your spaces are not optional here, you need at least one.

Comment: Yes, I've to use *, after reading those answers below I understand it. idk who's answer I should accept all the answers are great :D

Answer (score 1):

Your regex as written requires that there is one or more spaces.

If you want the spaces to be completely optional (not non-greedy), you should use `\s*?`.

If you want only one space or no space, then you should use `\s?`.

If you only want spaces and not other whitespace characters, you should use `[ ]*?`. I used the character class to make the space more explicit, but the `[]` are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

`/\s?/` matches a single space or no space.

`/\s*/` matches single/multiple spaces or no space.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator means one or more repetitions of. If you want to allow spaces optionally, meaning that they cannot simply not be there, you would need to use the `*` operator, which means 0 or more repetitions of.

Alternatively, you could use something like so: `(\s+?)?`, which essentially means that optionally, there can be one or more spaces.

That being said, sticking to `\s*?` will yield what you want through a cleaner regex.